# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с заданием

Tags: php

1.Создайте переменную и присвойте ей случайное значение — либо 0, либо 1 — по аналогии с предыдущими заданиями, через функцию rand(). Выведите это значение на экран.

$a = rand(0, 1);

2.Создайте вторую переменную и присвойте ей значение — либо null если значение первой переменной равно 0, либо случайное число от 1 до 3 в противном случае. Выведите это значение на экран.
Условие: присваивать значение второй переменной нужно через тернарный оператор.

у меня получилось так: `$b = $a ? null : rand(1, 3);`
дальше я не очень понимаю, что надо делать в задании... недавно начал изучение

3.Создайте конструкцию выбора, где:
а)в виде выражения используется вторая переменная;
б)в виде значений (case) используются следующие:
null,
1,
case по умолчанию.
В каждом конкретном случае (case) выведите на экран какой-то осмысленный текст.
4.После конструкции выбора выведите на экран с помощью функции var_dump() значение логического типа, которое будет показывать, установлено ли значение для второй переменной или нет (то есть там пустое значение null).
Подсказка: для проверки установленности значения используйте функцию isset().
5.В конце создайте переменную, которой присвойте значение второй переменной, только если она НЕ null. В противном случае присвойте случайное значение от 20 до 30. И выведите значение этой переменной на экран.
Условие: нужно воспользоваться null-коалесцентным оператором.

Answer (score 0):

3.Создайте конструкцию выбора, где: а)в виде выражения используется вторая переменная; б)в виде значений (case) используются следующие: null, 1, case по умолчанию. В каждом конкретном случае (case) выведите на экран какой-то осмысленный текст.

```
switch ($b) {
    case 1:
        echo '$b = 1';
        break;
    case null:
        echo '$b = null';
        break;

    default:
        echo '$b = ' . $b;
        break;
}
```

4.После конструкции выбора выведите на экран с помощью функции var_dump() значение логического типа, которое будет показывать, установлено ли значение для второй переменной или нет (то есть там пустое значение null). Подсказка: для проверки установленности значения используйте функцию isset().

```
var_dump(isset($b);
```

5.В конце создайте переменную, которой присвойте значение второй переменной, только если она НЕ null. В противном случае присвойте случайное значение от 20 до 30. И выведите значение этой переменной на экран.
Условие: нужно воспользоваться null-коалесцентным оператором.

```
$c = $b ?? $c = rand(20,30);
echo $c;
```